# OptKeras (Keras Optuna Wrapper) - use optkeras inside my own class, AttributeError: type object 'FrozenTrial' has no attribute '_field_types'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, optuna

I wrote a simple Keras code, in which I use CNN for fashion mnist dataset. Everything works great. I implemented my own class and classification is OK.

However, I wanted to use Optuna, as OptKeras (Optuna wrapper for Keras), you can see an example here: https://medium.com/@Minyus86/optkeras-112bcc34ec73.

However, something is wrong with my code. When I try to use optKeras inside my own class. Here's the code: (ordinary `run` method works, but `optuna_run` gives an error: `AttributeError: type object 'FrozenTrial' has no attribute '_field_types'`.

```
! pip install optkeras
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN 
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras import backend as K

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.metrics

import optuna
from optkeras.optkeras import OptKeras

import sys
import math
import numpy
import scipy.io as sio   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class OptunaTest():

  def __init__(self):
    self.fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
    (self.train_images, self.train_labels), (self.test_images, self.test_labels) = self.fashion_mnist.load_data()
    self.class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
    self.train_images = self.train_images / 255.0
    self.test_images = self.test_images / 255.0
    self.model = None 
    self.study_name = 'FashionMnist' + '_Simple'
    self.ok = OptKeras(study_name=self.study_name)

  def run(self):
    self.model = keras.Sequential()
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    self.model.fit(self.train_images, self.train_labels, epochs=5)
    test_loss, test_acc = self.model.evaluate(self.test_images, self.test_labels, verbose=0)
    predictions = self.model.predict(self.test_images)

    INDEX = 10
    print("\nPREDICTION: " + str(predictions[INDEX]))
    print("\nMAX PREDICTION VAL: " + str(numpy.argmax(predictions[INDEX])))
    print("\nLABEL: " + str(self.test_labels[INDEX]))

  def optuna_run(self, trial):
    K.clear_session() 
    
    self.model = keras.Sequential()
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = trial.suggest_categorical('units', [32, 64, 128]), activation = trial.suggest_categorical('activation', ['relu', 'linear'])))
    self.model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = trial.suggest_categorical('units', [32, 64, 128]), activation = trial.suggest_categorical('activation', ['relu', 'linear'])))

    self.model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
    self.model.fit(self.train_images, self.train_labels, epochs=5, callbacks = self.ok.callbacks(trial), verbose = self.ok.keras_verbose)
    test_loss, test_acc = self.model.evaluate(self.test_images, self.test_labels, verbose=0)
    predictions = self.model.predict(self.test_images)
    print(ok.trial_best_value)
    
    INDEX = 10
    print("\nPREDICTION: " + str(predictions[INDEX]))
    print("\nMAX PREDICTION VAL: " + str(numpy.argmax(predictions[INDEX])))
    print("\nLABEL: " + str(self.test_labels[INDEX]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  ot = OptunaTest()
  ot.run()

  ot.ok.optimize(ot.optuna_run,  timeout = 60)
```

A code can also be found here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uibWa80BdjatA5Kcw27eMUsS7SmwxaDk?usp=sharing.

The full error message:

```
[W 2020-06-30 11:09:26,959] Setting status of trial#0 as TrialState.FAIL because of the following error: AttributeError("type object 'FrozenTrial' has no attribute '_field_types'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py", line 230, in synch_with_optuna
    self.best_trial = self.study.best_trial
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optuna/study.py", line 97, in best_trial
    return copy.deepcopy(self._storage.get_best_trial(self._study_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optuna/storages/in_memory.py", line 293, in get_best_trial
    raise ValueError("No trials are completed yet.")
ValueError: No trials are completed yet.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optuna/study.py", line 734, in _run_trial
    result = func(trial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py", line 130, in fun_tf
    return fun(trial)
  File "<ipython-input-11-45495c9f2ae9>", line 65, in optima_run
    self.model.fit(self.train_images, self.train_labels, epochs=10, callbacks = self.ok.callbacks(trial), verbose = self.ok.keras_verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py", line 172, in callbacks
    self.synch_with_optuna()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py", line 232, in synch_with_optuna
    self.best_trial = get_trial_default()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py", line 367, in get_trial_default
    num_fields = optuna.structs.FrozenTrial._field_types.__len__()
AttributeError: type object 'FrozenTrial' has no attribute '_field_types'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py in synch_with_optuna(self)
    229         try:
--> 230             self.best_trial = self.study.best_trial
    231         except:

12 frames

ValueError: No trials are completed yet.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/optkeras/optkeras.py in get_trial_default()
    365 
    366 def get_trial_default():
--> 367     num_fields = optuna.structs.FrozenTrial._field_types.__len__()
    368     assert num_fields in (10, 11, 12)
    369     if num_fields == 12: # possible future version

AttributeError: type object 'FrozenTrial' has no attribute '_field_types'
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you to resolve the issue. If not - let me know which versions of `optuna`, `optkeras` and `tensorflow` you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that optkeras (version I got was 0.0.7) being not quite up-to-date with optuna library is the reason for the issue. I was able to make it work with optuna 1.5.0 by doing the following changes:

First, you'll need to monkey-patch `get_default_trial` like this before running your code:

```
import optkeras
optkeras.optkeras.get_trial_default = lambda: optuna.trial.FrozenTrial(
            None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

After doing so I'm getting an error with `Callback` saying:

```
AttributeError: 'OptKeras' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'
```

To solve this you'll have to manually edit optkeras.py, but not too much - just add `tensorflow.` to first two lines imports, i.e. make them:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback, CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint
```

instead of:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback, CSVLogger, ModelCheckpoint
```

If you can't change the code after installation it might be a bit of a problem - I would probably just recommend to copy full code of optkeras library (it's just one file optkeras.py) and use fixed version of that in your script or something like that. Unfortunately I don't see a nice way of monkey-patching this import issue. That said I think it can be fairly easy to either change that on-fly even from python (i.e. change `optkeras.py` lines from within python before importing optkeras) or copying the optkeras.py (also from withing python script) + replacing the strings on fly, then importing from the new location.

After that is done I just had to:

- fix typo in your code (`print(ok.trial_best_value)` should really be `print(self.ok.trial_best_value)`)
- add `validation_split=0.1` to `self.model.fit` call (or you may use something else for your tuning - just with existing code example callback won't get `val_loss` value because there is no validation set and optkeras is using `val_loss` by default - see `monitor` argument for `OptKeras` constructor). My guess would be that you probably will either want to create a fixed validation set instead or monitor training loss `loss` instead of `val_loss`.
- add `return test_loss` at the end of `optuna_run` method.

After all of these changes everything seems be working.

Comment: It will be hard to do (I will try) but I do this mostly on google colab.

Comment: I also tried with the simplest possible code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EOYHhRCMxHQmds6-Tk2Rn2CaaEMhu4Bt?usp=sharing. But still, the problem remains.

Comment: Your links to colab are blocked and make me request access - is that expected?

Comment: No, sorry, I will share it again: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EOYHhRCMxHQmds6-Tk2Rn2CaaEMhu4Bt?usp=sharing

Comment: Your colab is pretty much in a working state with the exception of using `val_acc` as monitor which is not produced by `model.fit` now for callbacks. If you e.g. switch monitor to be `val_loss` it works.

Comment: OK, thank you. I almost make it work, with your help of course :) There's one thing that isnt quite right. The code compiles, but now it shows: `Setting status of trial#2 as TrialState.FAIL because the returned value from the objective function cannot be casted to float. Returned value is: None`. Why? I do not understand it. Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uibWa80BdjatA5Kcw27eMUsS7SmwxaDk?usp=sharing

Comment: The last error is because you don't return anything in `optuna_run` method - you probably want to return `test_loss`.